# How to apply half circle mask to an ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, mask

I have an image, a half circle frame image and I need to put that image inside this frame. But I need to apply mask to my image so it is only displayed inside frame.

For example this is my image:

[image]

And my desired result should be like that:

[image]

The red frame also an image view which inside is transparent.

How can I achieve this in Android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a great tutorial on [Styling Android blog](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/irregular-shapes-part-1/) in four parts that explains how you can achieve this.

***Edit:***

I've edited the code in part two of the tutorial and created the effect:

```
private Bitmap processImage(Bitmap bitmap) {
    Bitmap bmp;

    bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),
            bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(bitmap,
            BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP,
            BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP);

    float radius = bitmap.getWidth() / 2f;
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setShader(shader);

    RectF rect = new RectF(-bitmap.getWidth() / 2f, 0,
            bitmap.getWidth() / 2f, bitmap.getHeight());
    canvas.drawOval(rect, paint);

    return bmp;
}
```

I just replaced the `drawRoundRect` at the end of the code with `drawOval` and it essentially draws a circle that half of it is out of canvas.

Comment: Thanks but how can I place the frame image onto this? Can I give width and height to this bitmap and then a little bigger width and height for frame?

Comment: Make your bitmap a bit bigger for the red frame, then before drawing the final image, draw the red frame:

`canvas.drawOval(rectRedFrame, paintRedFrame);`
`canvas.drawOval(rect, paint);`

Comment: Thanks again, but I have another question. Why fitXY doesnt apply to inner bitmap image?

Comment: Okey, I solved my issue by changing this line:  RectF rect = new RectF(-bitmap.getWidth() , 0,
            bitmap.getWidth() , bitmap.getHeight());